# Rxjs loading in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I got a problem as the below picture.

And my script in Contact.cshtml as the following

```
<script>
    System.config({
        map: {
            app: "/app",
            rxjs: '/lib/rxjs/Rx' // added this map section
        },
        packages:{
            app: { defaultJSExtensions:"js",},
            rxjs: { defaultExtension: "js" } // and added this to packages
        },
        paths: {
            '/app/*': '/app/*'
        },
    });
    System.import("/app/main")
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

and main.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";

import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "content-page",
    template: "Contact Test"
})

export class ContactPage{}
bootstrap(ContactPage, []);
```

What is the problem? 
Source code can be downloaded form https://github.com/lunyi/Plant.

[image: The error message]

Comment: The picture isn't visible. Please fix the link.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving Rxjs from the lib folder that might not have required files like Observable etc

do

```
npm install rxjs --save
```

Serve it from the node_modules

```
map: {
            app: "/app",
            rxjs: '/node_modules/rxjs/Rx' // added this map section
        },
```

Comment: Ya, I do as your comments. But now it occurs GET localhost:22773/lib/rxjs 404 (Not Found)  <br/> Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading localhost:22773/lib/rxjs(…)  <br/> GET localhost:22773/Home/symbol-observable 404 (Not Found)  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

Based on your source code, I think you just have a typo in your map object. I think your rxjs property should be set to this

```
<script>
System.config({
    map: {
        app: "/app",
        rxjs: '/lib/rxjs' // added this map section<------
    },
    packages:{
        app: { defaultJSExtensions:"js",},
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: "js" } // and added this to packages
    },
    paths: {
        '/app/*': '/app/*'
    },
});
System.import("/app/main")
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: Ya, you are right.
But now it occurs 
GET http://localhost:22773/lib/rxjs 404 (Not Found)  <br/>
Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading  <br/> http://localhost:22773/lib/rxjs(…)  <br/>
GET http://localhost:22773/Home/symbol-observable 404 (Not Found  <br/>